# Do your choices with MLA affect the game at all?

Tags: the-talos-principle

During the course of the game, you will be prompted by the MLA (Milton Library Assistant) who discusses philosophy with you. Often he makes you choose one of several options and eventually twists your words to contradict yourself.

I've tried restoring from an earlier checkpoint to replay some of these conversations again and he usually ends up saying exactly the same thing in the middle of or at the end of the conversation.

Do any of your conversations with the MLA actually affect the game at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various conversation choices with the MLA have no effect on the various endings of the game (regardless of your interactions with the MLA you can end your game 1 of 3 ways).

However there are 3 different achievements you can receive through different conversation options with the MLA.

[Press The Serpent](http://thetalosprinciple.gamepedia.com/Press_The_Serpent):

> Basically through a set of actions you can anger the MLA program.

[Silence The Serpent](http://thetalosprinciple.gamepedia.com/Silence_The_Serpent):

> Working with Elohim you can delete the MLA program.

[Deal With The Deceiver](http://thetalosprinciple.gamepedia.com/Deal_With_The_Deceiver):

> You end up befriending the MLA program and he asks that you take him to the top of the tower.